# Equality in $\mathbb{Z}$ versus equality in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: solution-verification, integers

I'm trying to rigorously understand a piece of a proof which involves the distinction between equality in $\mathbb{Z}$ and equality in $\mathbb{Q}$. To make this concrete, let $E$ denote the set of even natural numbers (I'll exclude $0$ for the moment) and define $f: \mathbb{N} \to E$ by $f(n) = 2n$. In an attempt to prove this map is injective, I would assume that $f(n) = f(m)$ for $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $2n = 2m$. I want to conclude that $n = m$ "by algebra," which would take the form of multiplying by $\frac{1}{2}$ and cancelling. My problem is: the "universe of discourse" here is the natural numbers, rather than the rational numbers. I think I could also say $2n = 2m$ implies $2n - 2m = 2(n-m) = 0$, and because $\mathbb{Z}$ lacks any zero divisors and $2 \neq 0$, we must have $n-m=0$. However, I think there is a way to justify the above algebra that I'm not seeing.

I'd appreciate any help in parsing this.

Comment: Your reasoning looks fine to me.

Comment: Ultimately this depends upon what axioms or background facts you're assuming.

Comment: I'm mainly concerned in whether there's a rigorous justification for the algebraic step or whether one can actually make that leap. I've seen the construction of $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$, for example, so I know that the embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ requires consistency for their shared elements. Is that enough to justify it?

Comment: It is as @GregMartin mentioned. Since $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$ you could multiply by ${1 \over 2}$ to conclude that the result is zero.

Comment: @copper.hat So is my above comment correct? That on $\mathbb{Z}$, we need the arithmetic of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ to coincide?

Comment: Yeah, no zero divisors can be applied to the natural numbers. You need a result that if $x+y=x+z$ then $y=z$ in the natural numbers. Then if $n\neq m$ then either $n=m+a$ or $m=n+a$ for some positive natural number $a.$ In the first case $2m=2n$ means $2m+2a=2m=2m+0,$ and hence $2a=0.$ Then you need to prove $a$ must be zero if $2a=0,$ which you can prove using the fact that $0$ is not the successor of any natural number, and if $a\neq 0$ then $a=b+1$ for some natural $b.$ Then $0=2(b+1)=(2b+1)+1$ so $0$ is the successor of a natural number.

Comment: Your first argument does depend on embedding the integers in the rationals. You can construct the rationals from the integers, so  you are using only properties of the integers, albeit indirectly. The second argument depends directly on the properties of the integers.

Comment: Without knowing your context it is hard to give a satisfactory answer. You don't **need** the rationals to arrive at the conclusion, it depends on your construction of the natural numbers or what properties you take as axioms.

Answer (score 1):

Working entirely in the naturals, you need:

> **Lemma 1:** If $x,y,z$ are natural numbers with $x+y=x+z,$ then $y=z.$

> **Lemma 2:** If $a$ is natural with $a\neq 0,$ then $a=b+1$ for some natural number $b.$

> **Lemma 3:** If $m,n$ are natural with $m\neq n,$ then there exists a non-zero natural $a$ such that either $m=n+a$ or $n=m+a.$

You also need the axiom that $0$ is not the successor of a natural number.

Now, assume $2m=2n.$ If $m\neq n,$ then find $a\neq 0$ as in Lemma $3.$

We'll assume $m=n+a.$ The other case is similar.

Then $$2n+0=2n=2m=2(n+a)=2n+2a$$ and hence, by Lemma $(1),$ $0=2a.$ But since $a\neq 0,$ by Lemma 2, we can find $b$ such that $a=b+1.$ Then $$0=2(b+1)=(2b+1)+1,$$ with makes $0$ the successor of a natural number. Contradiction.

So $m=n.$

---

The lemmas are proven by induction of varying degrees of complexity. $(3)$ is the hardest.

$(2)$ can be proven using one of the most comical induction proofs, if we rephrase it as:

> For all natural $a,$ either $a=0$ or $a=b+1$ for some natural $b.$

Comment: I think I might see (2) as a way of constructing $\mathbb N$. I suppose it depends on the axioms you're using, but it seems like a proof by induction would be circular: to show it is true for $a$, you show either it is the base case ($a = 0$) or that it follows from the case for $a-1$, but this would be exactly assuming $b := a-1 \in \mathbb N$ to apply the induction hypothesis, i.e. assuming that $a = b+1$ and $b$ is a natural.

Comment: It follows from the Peano axioms. "Constructing" the naturals is not an axiomatic approach, but a model theoretic approach. The induction proof is so simple, it is surprising, but it is entirely valid - what it shows is that the lemma is already encoded as a part of induction. That is why 8t **feels** circular.  @George